# copy a value in document into another document in mongodb using command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to copy the value of a key of a document in the same collection?

example:
from the below document to

```
{
"_id" : "werty4567tfdxc6ytf",
"thumbnail" : "somelargebase64encodedstring",
"other1" : "value"
}

{
"_id" : "sdf4567g67h8njomioh"
// thumbnail in the above document need to go here
"other2": "value" // these values shouldnt be replaced by above doc values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $merge.

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.t.insert({ "_id" : "werty4567tfdxc6ytf", "thumbnail" : "somelargebase64encodedstring" })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

MongoDB Enterprise > db.t.aggregate([{$set:{_id:'sdf4567g67h8njomioh'}}])
{ "_id" : "sdf4567g67h8njomioh", "thumbnail" : "somelargebase64encodedstring" }

MongoDB Enterprise > db.t.aggregate([{$set:{_id:'sdf4567g67h8njomioh'}},{$merge:'t'}])

MongoDB Enterprise > db.t.find()
{ "_id" : "werty4567tfdxc6ytf", "thumbnail" : "somelargebase64encodedstring" }
{ "_id" : "sdf4567g67h8njomioh", "thumbnail" : "somelargebase64encodedstring" }
```

Comment: Thanks but it is throwing the below error $merge is not supported when the output collection is the same as the aggregation collection",

Comment: Also, i dont want any changes to second record except the thumbail. Please consider my question i have edited.

Comment: The example I gave uses the same collection for reading and writing. Use $set to set any other fields you want.